# How to update Android in-app billing to the latest version?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app

I am using in-app billing 3 in my apps. I want to update to in-app billing 5. How do I do that? I have searched without finding any info. Is the only thing I should do to update the IInAppBillingService.aidl file? No other files need to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer versions just seem to add extra functionalty to the existing API so yes, I believe you would just need to change the AIDL file to use the new features.

Comment: It says here that version 5 was released last year:https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html

Comment: I see. It seems the documentation is conflicting. The updated AIDL files just simply seem to add extra functionality so I believe you are correct and would just need to update the AIDL if you wish to use the newer functions. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to android SDK manager in the IDE you are developing the code. there you can see the list of SDKs you have installed. You can see the update for the billing SDK there. Select the SDK and update.

Comment: I believe he needs to manually add the IInAppBillingService.aidl file from updated Google Play Billing Library. It won't just get reflected automatically  in your project.

Comment: Exactly, that is how it is!